# Missing Searchbar in VSCode settings.json Interface

Tags: user-interface, settings, visual-studio-code, searchbar

I have lost the search bar that was there at the top when I open my settings.json file which let me search settings with ease.
Now I need to search using Ctrl + F

Does anyone know how can I restore that search bar or what to change?

Here is the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Do you mean [this bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDLsQ.png) ?

Comment: Not this one, the one where I can type any setting and it will find it for me in split settings.json editor. The fuzzy search. @TimothyG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I was too having this issue and after some research, it seems like the fuzzy search was deprecated with the split editor. I'm sad...

Here is the link to the discussion on GitHub:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125952

If you want the "old" settings back, for now, you will have to revert to the 1.58.2 version. Here's the comment that has a link to the files: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125952#issuecomment-894709624

You will also have to disable auto-updates, which can only be done by (ironically) adding these lines to the settings.json

```
{
  "update.enableWindowsBackgroundUpdates": false,
  "update.mode": "manual"
}
```

Comment: I am feeling very sad too, I really liked it. But anyways I will continue with Ctrl+f for finding and searching rather than disabling my updates. I earlier thought I messed with my settings and changed something on my own, now I know it was an update from their side. Well, Thank you @Nando